Minilibx - multi-thread synchronization problem
I'm a student trying to use the minilibx library to render some graphics. I've split the rendering part and the calculation into two separate part, rendering part is a while loop constantly checking if there is a frame to display (there is a frame calculated). Calculation part is hooked on to the loop function which just loops the function until the program terminates.
The problem is in the synchronization of these two threads. I've implemented a counter so that each time calculation part is finished it increments the counter. If counter is greater than 0 render part will start rendering the frame. If calculation is very fast it could potentially write to the frame buffer that rendering thread is currently working on so i've used triple buffering and that frame counter cannot go over 2. (This way if rendering is being done on index 0, calculation would stop at 2 and wait for the rendering too be finished)
mlx_put_image_to_windows function I think just calls the metal and returns immediately, doing the frame rendering asynchronously. Because of this I've tried to use mlx_sync right after the call but it seems like synchronization isn't working quiet right. When I do mlx_sync in the calculation thread right before the calculation it seems to work fine. (At least it seems to that it works fine).
Below is my repository.
https://github.com/42seoul-sunghwki/cub3D
I've tried calling the mlx_sync function. I feel like the minilibx library is very poorly documented. I had to go through the source code to get the feel of how it might be working. I want to know why one works and one doesn't. I have a feeling that mlx_sync is called too soon for it to realize frame_render call since its async but just a guess.
Below is the student made docs for the minilibx library.
https://harm-smits.github.io/42docs/libs/minilibx

What do you hope to learn from such an old framework?

No, we (generally) will not go to your repository to study your code.  Whatever code you want us to refer to -- and it should be reasonably minimal -- should be presented in the question itself, as properly-formatted text.  If you're unsure what's relevant, or if that seems to be too much code, then I'm sorry, but the question isn't ready for SO yet.
